# Trouble harvesting a webpage giving wrong results

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've written a script in python to get the result populated against putting a `postcode` in an inputbox in a webpage. I only want to see the required response in the console.

[Website link](https://finddrivinginstructor.dvsa.gov.uk/DSAFindNearestWebApp/findNearest.form?lang=en)

Postcode I've tried with:

```
SW1A2AA
```

I've written so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://finddrivinginstructor.dvsa.gov.uk/DSAFindNearestWebApp/findNearest.form"

payload = {
    'postcode': 'SW1A2AA'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    res = s.post(link,data=payload,headers={
        'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0',
        'origin':'https://finddrivinginstructor.dvsa.gov.uk',
        })
    print(res.text)
```

Output I'm getting:

```
<html style="height:100%"><head><META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"><meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"><meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"><script type="text/javascript" src="/_Incapsula_Resource?SWJIYLWA=719d34d31c8e3a6e6fffd425f7e032f3"></script></head><body style="margin:0px;height:100%"><iframe src="/_Incapsula_Resource?SWUDNSAI=29&xinfo=8-25811410-0%200NNN%20RT%281565517742037%20111%29%20q%280%20-1%20-1%200%29%20r%280%20-1%29%20B12%2811%2c171583%2c0%29%20U6&incident_id=957001050101826332-146401351985596056&edet=12&cinfo=0b000000" frameborder=0 width="100%" height="100%" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px">Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: 957001050101826332-146401351985596056</iframe></body></html>
```

Desired output is anything from the result page.

***How can I get anything from the result page?***

Comment: The search results are being generated on the 'click' so need to use Selenium.

Comment: The site is protected by Incapsula, a Web-Application Firewall that also provides Bot detection. The easy solution is to copy valid cookies from a browser, but I'll see if I can get them programmatically with `requests`.

Comment: I think the problem is that `requests` doesn't have those cookies: `AWSALB` and `nlbi_1979198`, that are acquired by visiting https://finddrivinginstructor.dvsa.gov.uk/_Incapsula_Resource?SWJIYLWA=719d34d31c8e3a6e6fffd425f7e032f3 (I think). The page includes Js code that is obfuscated in at least two layers. If we manage to deobfuscate the code, it may be useful.

Comment: When I find you in a loop, things become clearer and easier.

Comment: Thanks man, I'm doing the best I can. However, it may not be so easy to clear the Js code - It's really long and heavily obfuscated, with names like `_0xeb8ab8`. A quick google search lead me to https://github.com/ziplokk1/incapsula-cracker-py3, which seemed promissing but it didn't produce results. The good thing is that if we figure this out we can create a github repo;)

Comment: Using an online deobfuscator - http://www.jsnice.org/ I managed to clear the Js code, and uploaded it here: https://pastebin.com/6pwqCcDP. The code is pretty easy to read now but still it's 1K lines. If I can find some time, I'll study it over the next days but I can't promiss anything.

Comment: That site is very good at banning ips. I'm rotationally using vpn to reach the solution. [This is how](https://pastebin.com/XCEztNyA) I'm trying. It seems I need to use cookies within headers as the current approach fetches me the content of the landing page where I initiated search..

Comment: Incapsula/Imperva is a WAF designed to detect and prevent hackers, so it can detect automated requests easily. Maybe I should have warned you about that. You should be careful not to issue too many requests in a short period of time, but spread them as much as possible. Of course, that doesn't guarantee that it will not detect you but I think it is more likely that it won't. About the second issue, I managed to get results with your Selenium-requests code by removing the `?lang=en` part of the URL.

Comment: Did you try the code that I posted?  It will perform the search and can collect the results once you plug that piece in.

Comment: I'm doing some question housekeeping. I was wondering if you ever tried my code?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some basic code to search your target site using Selenium. I did not add the results piece, but it's easy to add.

[Chrome Drivers](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

[Selenium docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Initiate Chrome Driver
chrome_options = Options()

# NOTE: This code was written on a MAC so this piece might need changed
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)

# Open Search Page
target_url = 'https://finddrivinginstructor.dvsa.gov.uk/DSAFindNearestWebApp/findNearest.form?lang=en'
driver.get(target_url)

WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'search-form')))

postcode = driver.find_element_by_id('postcode')
postcode.send_keys('SW1A2AA')

search_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search-form"]/fieldset/div/button')
search_button.click()
```

Comment: Sorry @Life is complex, for my belated response. I never did try your suggestion as my intention was to stick with requests module only. Thanks.

Comment: No worries.  Sometimes you just wonder if your efforts were useful.  Thanks for the response.